# Can I recover my conflict resolutions after running git rebase --skip?

Tags: git

I just spent a really long time fixing conflicts during a rebase. Then I added the conflicting files, and I ran `git rebase --continue` as you're supposed to. I got this message:

> You must edit all merge conflicts and then
> mark them as resolved using git add

Looking around online, I saw that a common solution for this error was to run git rebase --skip. So I did. All my conflict resolutions are gone. All the changes in the commit I wanted to add on top of the other branch are gone. The "rebase" basically just turned my branch into the other one. Clearly I didn't understand the skip command.

Is there any hope in recovering the conflict resolutions that were added, but not committed because of `skip`? Or do I just have to start over with a new rebase?

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to start over, as the changes you made were not committed or stashed.  If you are using a powerful IDE such as IntelliJ, then you might be able to recover the changes via the local history.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks! I actually remembered that independently after posting. I do use IntelliJ and I was able to revert the changes imposed by git while it skipped. Basically I reverted the most recent change to each of the affected files and made a normal commit. It worked well since I was only applying one (huge) commit and this didn't happen in the middle of a long rebase.

Comment: That's great to hear.  Next time be more careful while rebasing `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Just to have an answer to close this out (or you could close your question yourself): the short answer for Git itself is generally no.  However, if you *did* run `git add`, you can *sometimes* retrieve various file contents, using Git's low-level ("plumbing") operations and `git fsck`.  Git will have wiped out the *names* that go with these file-contents, so you'll have files with hash-ID names like `d6602ec5194c87b0fc87103ca4d67251c76f233a` instead of `my-file.txt`.

If you can recover the files by some means *outside* Git (such as editor backups or file system snapshots: on a Mac, for instance, you can try Time Machine and just go back an hour), that's typically far easier, and therefore the way to go.

If you did not even use `git add` on the updated files, they have been removed, and their data were never even *in* Git in the first place, so Git can't possibly retrieve their data.  The way to understand this is to realize that a Git repository in which you do work consists of separate parts:

- There is the repository proper, inside the `.git` directory (or folder) at the top level of your working tree.  This is where Git stores all its own stuff.  You're free to look around inside here, but unless you know what you're doing, you shouldn't change anything inside this directory.
- There is Git's *index*, in `.git/index`.  This contains the proposed *next* commit.  Every time you run `git add`, Git updates its index, and that's why (and part of how) you can get `add`-ed files back.  Note that the index really contains the file's *name*, *mode*, and *hash ID*, plus a bunch of temporary cache data having to do with OS-level `lstat` system calls.  The file's data are in an internal Git-only object called a *blob object*, which is named by hash ID.  That's why the files' *names* are lost even if you can get their data back: there's only this one index, which contains what Git needs to make the *next* commit, and if you don't actually make a commit from it and overwrite it, all of its data are lost.
- Finally, there is your *working tree*.  The files here are in some sense merely temporary.  They are *your* files, to do with as you please, but some Git operations—like `git checkout`, `git switch`, `git restore`, `git reset --hard`, and the like—are requests that Git *wipe out* these files and put in some *other* files instead.  Some of these, like `git switch`, run some safety checks first; others, like `git reset --hard`, don't.

The files in your working tree are, literally, *not in Git*.  They're just there in your working tree, so that you have files that you can work with and/or update.  The *committed* files are in a special Git-only format, compressed and de-duplicated, in those hash-ID-named *blob objects*.  (The files' names are stored separately, in more hash-ID named objects, called *tree objects*.  Committing build a tree from the index, then builds a commit that refers to this tree, so that the files are now saved forever, instead of just for 14 days or so.  Of course any files that *are* duplicates are already saved forever, thanks to being in some existing commit(s).)